# Manipulation of sums (in order to understand proof regarding Gauss sums)

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analysis, summation

I'm looking over the proof of $\left| \tau(\chi) \right|=\sqrt{q}$, when $\chi$ is a primitive character mod $q$, and $\tau$ the Gauss sum. (H. L. Montgomery and R. C. Vaughan. Multiplicative number theory. I. Theorem. 9.7) Anyhow, this is a universal exercise in manipulation of sums.

I need to simplify

$\sum_{a=1}^q\sum_{b=1}^q \chi (a) \overline{\mathbb{\chi(b)}}\mathbb{1}_{a=b} \cdot q$

I'm thinking something like this:

$\sum_{a=1}^q\sum_{b=1}^q \chi (a) \overline{\mathbb{\chi(b)}}\mathbb{1}_{a=b}\cdot q
= \sum_{a=1}^q\sum_{a=1}^q\left| \chi(a) \right| ^2 \cdot q
= \sum_{a=1}^q\sum_{a=1}^q \mathbb{1}_{gcd\left( a,q \right) =1} \cdot q = \phi(q) \cdot q$

where $\phi$ is the Euler phi-function. But this computation seems "illegal" to me. How would one do this?

(I need to end up with the expression $\phi(q) \cdot q$)

Comment: It looks fine to me, except that once $b$ is gone there should only be one sum on $a$, not two.

Comment: That's nice. But I can't get my head around why I can just delete the one sum after I let $a=b$.

Comment: Because you're just summing over $a$ from $1$ to $q$. That's a single sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a derivation with an intermediate step which might be helpful.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{a=1}^q}&\color{blue}{\sum_{b=1}^q \chi (a) \overline{\chi(b)}\mathbb{1}_{a=b}\cdot q}\\
> &=q\sum_{a=1}^q\left(\chi (a) \overline{\chi(a)}+\sum_{{b=1}\atop{b\ne a}}^q \chi (a) \overline{\chi(b)}\right)\mathbb{1}_{a=b}\\
> &=q\sum_{a=1}^q\chi (a) \overline{\chi(a)}\cdot 1
> +q\sum_{a=1}^q\sum_{{b=1}\atop{b\ne a}}^q \chi (a) \overline{\chi(b)}\cdot 0\\
> &=q\sum_{a=1}^q\left|\chi (a)\right|^2=q\sum_{a=1}^q \mathbb{1}_{\gcd\left( a,q \right) =1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=q\phi(q)}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense to me now!

Comment: @slowpoke: You're welcome!